# Constructing merge sort worst case for 5 elements

Tags: sorting, merge

Is there an algorithm to figure out the worst case scenario (most comparisons) for mergesort for an array? Let us say that the sorted array looks like this:

```
a_1, a_2, a_3, a_4, a_5
```

What would it have to look before? I have read on the page that it would have to be alternating elements, but why is that so? What is especially confusing me is the uneven number of elements (not all subarrays will have the same size).

Comment: For a standard merge sort, the number of moves is always the same. The number of compares depends on the data pattern. The pattern doesn't have to be alternating elements, just one where the final compare is for the last element in each of the two runs being compared during a merge step. For 5 elements, the data pattern won't affect compare overhead when merging two 1 element runs. The variation will occur when merging a 2 element run with a 1 element run (1 compare if 1 element run has smallest element, else 2 compares), and when merging a 2 element run with a 3 element run (2 to 4 compares).

Comment: How does one get 2 compares when comparing a two array to a three array?

Comment: Nevermind, my question was naive, both compared to the lowest of the 3 array.